# Will this become a problem for remaining in the UK once married?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, weddings

Short story, I've had difficulty at the UK border in the past. Turned away as they suspected I was coming for work. After about a year, I decided to visit Ireland and they let me through on a visitor visa (US passport). A few months later, I came back through Ireland with the purpose of going to the UK. Ireland didn't like this and turned me away. So I have a refusal of entry in both Ireland and the UK.

Again, about a year passed and this time I went through Heathrow with no issues, again on my passport as a visitor. I was in the UK for about a few months and returned home since then but in that time I was there I met someone and he's asked me to marry him.

I don't want there to be any problem being together with him with my immigration history. Will I be able to live in the UK when we get married or will our only option be him coming to live with me in the US?

Comment: Questions about long term residence can be asked on our sister site [expatriates.se].

Comment: A history of being turned away as a visitor shouldn’t really have any material detrimental effect on an application for a spouse visa to settle in the UK, provided of course that you meet the requirements for the latter.

Comment: What do you mean by the term *turned away*? Did you fly to Europe, were not let in and took the next plane back?

Comment: You might review this UK government page, which discusses the requirements for obtaining a spouse visa. The requirements are not trivial. https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse